# Connection string for an embedded sqlite file

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2012

I have been messing around with sqlite databases and using them in my application.  I have a small issue though.  I want to package the file with the application.  My first thought was to embed it in the resource file but I can't seem to connect to it.

I am pretty new to this and I don't really know my options.  If I add the file to my project, how do I get at it or reference it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQLite connection strings are file system based, just add the file to your project, and then set its `Build Action` to `Copy Always` by hitting F4 when on the file in Solution Explorer.

This will copy the file to your output directory, generally `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`.

Comment: So If I put it into the resources folder I can reference it by resources\Sqlite.sqlite?

Comment: @Herrozerro, nope, not at all. Just add it to your project -the root -and set its build action. When you do this you won't need anything but `Sqlite.sqlite` as the data source because it will be in the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: Spoke a little too soon, that worked, but when i try to publish the app it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Herrozerro, this is actually a valid approach because you **generally** wouldn't want to overwrite a database that has production data in it. However, setting its `BuildAction` to `Content` instead of `None` will probably include it in the publish operation.

Comment: Ah, I just want to include this blank database for filling with data after the application starts.

Comment: @Herrozerro, then just move it there on the first deployment. That is an unfortunate reality of leveraging databases.